# Adding String to a List - Quicker way?

Tags: c#, string, list, addition

Is there a quicker or more efficient way to add Strings to a List than the below example?:

```
List<String> apptList = new List<String>();

foreach (Appointment appointment in appointments){

    String subject = appointment.Subject;
    //...(continues for another 10 lines)

    //...And then manually adding each String to the List:   
    apptList.Add(subject);
    //...(continues for another 10 lines)

    //And then send off List apptList to another method
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `//...(continues for another 10 lines)`? Are there 10 other fields where you have `String fieldname = appointment.FieldName;`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var apptList = appointments.Select(a => a.Subject).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Keith. I'm a little confused about the "appointments.Select(a => a.Subject)" part. Does this mean the for each statement is now redundant as this references 'appointments' rather than each 'appointment', or am I mistaken? Also, what does the 'a => a.Subject' reference, I have not come across that before. Cheers.

Comment: It basically means for every item in appointments, Select the subject,  and then turn that into a list.  So you end up with a list of strings which are all the appointment subjects.   This is using Linq.  If you haven't looked at Linq, its fantastic! worth the time investigating.   It can do a whole lot more than just that.

Comment: oh, and yes, means the foreach is redundant for creating a list of subjects

Comment: and potentially whatever else is in your foreach can be turned into Linq

Comment: Haha great, thanks Keith. I am doing some XML handling and am currently using XMLSerializer, although I did look at Linq for this as well.

Comment: Linq to XML is good,  and potentially useful with XPath as well

Comment: So just to double check, I'm wanting to get the subject, location, start time, end time, etc, for an appointment (out of many appointments), I can still use your above line of code? I'd just have to change it a bit so instead of getting all the subject lines from all appointments, I only get one...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30871/discussion-between-keith-nicholas-and-lbran)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your code right, but since your Appointment class is already implementing IEnumerable, you should be able to call ToList() to convert it to a list in one shot.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx

Comment: apptList = appointment.Subject.ToList(); - Gets an error message connot implicitly convert type char to String. What am I doing wrong? :/

Comment: need to see the code. If you need to create string from array of char, string newString = new string(charArray). If you're trying to convert a list of chars to string, newString = new string(charList.ToArray())

Comment: I just find it strange as Subject is of type String, no idea where the 'char' came from...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
List<string> apptList = appointments.Select(x => x.Subject).ToList();
```